# why should i use single quotes for application.run in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

i have this:

```
Application.Run ("'L:\database\lcmsmacro\macro1.xlsm'!macro_name")
```

why should i use the single quotes? does it not recognize the backslash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's for consistency.

Single quotes are necessary when the path contains spaces ot exclamation marks, so to make things more consistent and simple, the quotes are required every time.

Comment: Thanks for solving a problem that had me banging my head against the wall. This isn't made clear in the Excel 2003 help or in anything I found on MSDN!